# No more bash history, new hidden folders in www directory, what happens to my server?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh

For a while, when I access my ubuntu 18.04 server on vultr, by clicking the up arrow, I no longer see the bash history. It is always empty, even if I write some commands, then I exit the server and re-enter, the bash history is empty again.

I immediately thought it was the fault of some updates.

But the other day I noticed new hidden folders in my /www directory

```
/www
    .local
    .config
    .ssh
```

and a new file: .bash_history
Inside the file is this:

```
su
sudo cat ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh localhost
ssh localhost -p 65262
ssh localhost -p 65262 -u root
ssh root@localhost:65262
ssh root@127.0.0.1:65262
ssh root@localhost -p 65262
ssh root@localhost -p 65262 -i /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh root@localhost -p 65262 -i "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key"
su root
su myuser
```

65262 is my old ssh port, I changed it, just for sure.

What's happening to my server? Is there anyone playing with it without my knowing it?

On my server I disabled the ssh login with password, disabled the root user, installed fail2ban with filter on ssh, changed the ssh port.

And so far I haven't seen any changes to my sites or my files.

I can't understand if it's just an update and a normal server behavior or if it's something more dangerous. Can you help me understand?

**Update**

I pasted the echo in a terminal, this is the result, but I have no idea if it is correct, wrong or if there is something strange.

```
HISTFILE=
HISTFILESIZE=2000
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PS1=[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

if I write this:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_logout
```

I see this:

```
# ~/.bash_logout: executed by bash(1) when login shell exits.

# when leaving the console clear the screen to increase privacy

if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
fi
```

It's normal???

And .profile comments say this, and seem to use the new dir I saw on my www:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Review access times in "last" command. It sounds like someone has accessed your server and wiped history file

Comment: I have a snapshot of my server about a month ago on vultr.

I could restore it, but it is the same server... How do I put it to safety?

If someone entered once, will not have problems to enter again on the same server...

What can I do?

Comment: Assuming login credentials are the same on backup, I would assume restoring it is not safe. Contact vultr, maybe they can take it offline and examine the server that way. You can of course change passwords but if the attacker left a backdoor method to access it, that wont help much

Comment: vultr does nothing on your server. Better to develop a new server? :(

Comment: Yes, just to be safe

Comment: but how can I increase security?

Comment: There's whole books written on the security subject, but just start with disabling `root` login via ssh, using ssh keys instead of just password login, ensure there's minimum applications exposed to the internet on the ports, keep SQL databases ( if you do have them )  accessible only locally  and not via network, and keep the software updated

Answer (score 0):

NOT normal behaviour! Read `man bash`, the 'INVOCATION' section. Carefully inspect `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bash_logout`, and `~/.profile`. Additionally, look at  all files `source`'d (or `.`ed) in those files.

In a running shell, look at

```
echo "HISTFILE=$HISTFILE"
echo "HISTFILESIZE=$HISTFILESIZE"
echo "PATH=$PATH"
echo "PS1=$PS1"
```

Comment: You talk to me, but I don't understand what you're saying... I'm not a Linux expert, I'm a PHP programmer... Can you explain everything as if you were talking to someone who knows almost nothing about Linux? Thank you.

Comment: Your attempts to add information via comments, shows why we ask you to Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1148919/edit ) your Question to add info, and use the `{}` formatting tool. The first thing I think I see is `HISTFILE=`, when it should be the name of the history file. I won't decode the rest of the comments. Please edit and format.

Comment: Good now? It's ok?